# How do you get HubContext in SignalR 3?

Tags: signalr

In SignalR 2 you could do something like this (taken from my blog):

```
var stockTickerHub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<StockTickerHub>();
```

That allows you to get a reference to the SignalR hub from outside the hub (e.g. from a stock ticker thread).

This does not seem to be available in SignalR 3. How do you achieve the equivalent functionality in the new and upcoming SignalR?

Answer (score 2):

I asked the same thing to the creator of `SignalR`, David Fowler on [Jabbr](https://jabbr.net/account/login?ReturnUrl=%2F), a forum where the creators of SignalR and the architects of `ASP.NET 5` hang on from time to time, and his answer to this question was to use `dependency injection`.

While I haven't tried it yet with `SignalR 3`, I am pretty sure you can inject an instance of `ConnectionManager` that implements `IConnectionManager` in your class, and use it just like you would use `GlobalHost` to resolve your hub context.

Again, I have not done this with `SignalR3`, but I hope this will get you a little closer to finding a solution.

I put together a [sample for using `SignalR 2` with Autofac. (In this repo](https://github.com/radu-matei/SignalRDependencyInjection) I use `Autofac` to inject dependencies in my hub, but also to inject instances of a `ConnectionManager` in other classes to get the hub context).

Hope this helps. Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

Dependency injection is indeed the way and works.

Example:

```cs
public class ChatController : Controller
{
    readonly IConnectionManager _connectionManager;

    public ChatController(IConnectionManager connectionManager)
    {
        _connectionManager = connectionManager;
    }

    public IActionResult Chat(string message)
    {
        IHubContext context = _connectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
        IConnection connection = _connectionManager.GetConnectionContext<PersistentConnection>().Connection;

        context.Clients.All.NewMessage(message);

        return new EmptyResult();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From every example I have seen and the few SignalR 3 apps I have implemented, you no longer have a strongly typed reference to your hub. The current methodology connects to a hub via the hub's name and URL. The On generic method creates a subscription to broadcasts from that hub and the method name you provide.

```
HubConnection connection = new HubConnection(ServerURL); 
IHubProxy hubProxy = connection.CreateHubProxy("StockTickerHub"); 
hubProxy.On<StockTickerMessage>("[Your method name here]", msg => {
    //your UI update logic here 
});
```